# Write the equation of a possible rational function with the following characteristics.

Tags: calculus

Write the equation of a possible rational function with the following characteristics.  Explain your reasoning.
Vertical asymptotes

$a) \quad$ Vertical asymptotes at $\;x = \pm 3$, $x$-intercepts at $x = 5 \;\;and \; x = -1,$ and a horizontal
$\quad\quad$ asymptote of $y = \dfrac 12$

$b) \quad$ Vertical asymptotes at $x = \dfrac 14,\;$ $x$-intercept of $\,x = 0,\;$ and a discontinuous point at $\,\left(5,\dfrac 5{19}\right)$

$c) \quad$ $Y$-intercept at $-5, \,$ no $x$-intercepts, discontinuous points at $\,(-1, -5)\;and\; (3, -5)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Whilst this may theoretically be a question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the question here, and provide the link for reference. Unless you show some serious work, nobody here is likely to get interested enough to solve it, even less to share the solution with you.

Comment: Some thoughts to help you work:  y-intercept is when x=0, vertical asymptote is a factor in the denominator, horizontal asymptote is the limit as $x \to \infty$  Try applying these and putting the problem in the question (showing your work) if you get stuck.

Comment: okay I can't figure out please help.

Answer (score 1):

(a). Vertical asymptotes at $x=±3$ imply that the denominator could be $x^2-9$, $x$-intercepts at $x=5$ and $x=−1$ imply that the numerator could be $(x-5)(x+1)$, and a horizontal asymptote of $y=\frac{1}{2}$ implies that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Putting all the argument together, the function is
$$ f(x)=\frac{(x-5)(x+1)}{2(x^2-9)}. $$
You can use the same reasoning for (b) and (c). Now I do not have time and I will come back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, a. is [(x-5)(x+1)]/[2(x-3)(x+3)]

Comment: You have to give your reasoning.

Comment: @user72311: Can you provide more details to make your answer clearer to the OP? I think it would really help. Regards